# Pushing to GitHub repo writes changes in a folder with same name as repo

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a GitHub repo (https://github.com/userName/packageName). I usually push changes from my local computer to the GitHub repo using:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

I am not sure what I did. However, now, when I issue this command, I notice that it only pushes changes to my GitHub repo in a duplicately named subfolder (https://github.com/userName/packageName/packageName). I also notice that it created a "Compare and Pull Request" button on my GitHub repo page with the same packageName.

I double-checked that my local computer does not have the packageName duplicated (my directory is just /Users/userName/packageName). Running `git branch -a` shows:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/RELEASE_3_10
  remotes/origin/packageName
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/RELEASE_3_10
  remotes/upstream/RELEASE_3_9
  remotes/upstream/master
```

How can I fix this problem and push all my changes to simply my GitHub repo (https://github.com/userName/packageName) and not (https://github.com/userName/packageName/packageName)?

Comment: Try to run `git remote -v`. This prints all information about where git pushes and pulls from.

Comment: Thanks @vatbulb. I get: origin https://github.com/userName/packageName (fetch)
origin https://github.com/userName/packageName (push)
upstream git@git.bioconductor.org:packages/packageName.git (fetch)
upstream git@git.bioconductor.org:packages/packageName.git (push)

Comment: So, at least according to my `git remote -v` output, it is not pointing at a redundant name having `packageName/packageName` format.

Comment: Yeah, looks ok to me, too. In that case, I have no clue 

Comment: Now, when I try to do `git add .`, `git commit -m 'message'`, it outputs: `warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.` and it gives me a list of `Untracked files:` mostly all two folders up `../`

Answer (score 0):

Likely not an elegant answer but I ended up:

1) Deleting the local package folder entirely
2) Cloning the GitHub repo into a new local package folder
3) Deleting the redundant folder name locally
4) Pushing changes to GitHub

This simultaneously removed the "Compare and Pull Request" button" and the redundant folder with the same packageName on my GitHub repo.